# Recycler View not showing views properly in height and width parameter

Tags: android, layout, android-recyclerview

I have been working on an app in which recycler view is used. This is what I wish it to be looked:

[image: expecation]

but right now, my code is showing like this:

[image: My work]

I have like stuck at this point where views are not properly created in recyclerview {like 3-4 blank tabs in starting) and i need my app to look better. I am attaching my code below:
MainActivity Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    public Cursor cursor;
    public StudentRepo studentRepo;
    private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName().toString();

    private static final String TAG_BOOKMARKS="bookmarks";
    private static final String TAG_ABOUT_US="about";

    //recyclerView implementation
    private List<TopSample> wordlist=new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private StudentAdapter studentAdapter;
    //recyclerView implementation done



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        studentRepo = new StudentRepo(this);






        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
        databaseAccess.open();
        Cursor cursor= databaseAccess.getInfo();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
            TopSample topSample=new TopSample(cursor.getString(0));
               wordlist.add(topSample);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        databaseAccess.close();

        studentAdapter=new StudentAdapter(wordlist);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(studentAdapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                TopSample topSample= wordlist.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SearchResult.class);
                intent.putExtra(SearchResult.EXTRA_NO, (int) position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        //Done recyclerview implement

        ImageView imageView=new ImageView(this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_action);

        FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
                .setContentView(imageView)
                .build();
        ImageView Bookmarks=new ImageView(this);
        Bookmarks.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_action);
        ImageView Aboutus=new ImageView(this);
        Aboutus.setImageResource(R.drawable.button_action);
        SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(this);
        SubActionButton buttonbookmark = itemBuilder.setContentView(Bookmarks).build();
        SubActionButton buttonaboutus = itemBuilder.setContentView(Aboutus).build();
        buttonbookmark.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonaboutus.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonbookmark.setTag(TAG_BOOKMARKS);
        buttonaboutus.setTag(TAG_ABOUT_US);


        FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(this)
                .addSubActionView(buttonbookmark)
                .addSubActionView(buttonaboutus)
                .attachTo(actionButton)
                .build();



    }

public interface ClickListener{
    void onClick(View view, int position);
    void onLongClick (View view, int position);
}

    public static class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{
        private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
        private MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener;

        public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView,final MainActivity.ClickListener clickListener){
            this.clickListener = clickListener;
            gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                    View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                        clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
                clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
            }


            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    ///@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);


      // if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchView search = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
            search.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

            search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextSubmit ");
                    //cursor = studentRepo.getStudentListByKeyword(s);
                   // if (cursor == null) {
                     //   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No records found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   // } else {
                      //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, cursor.getCount() + " records found!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   // }/
                    //customAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onQueryTextChange ");
                    final List<TopSample>filteredmodellist=filter(wordlist,s);
                    studentAdapter.setFilter(filteredmodellist);

                    // cursor = studentRepo.getStudentListByKeyword(s);
                    // if (cursor != null) {
                    //      customAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
                    //  }
                    return true;
                }
                private List<TopSample>filter(List<TopSample>models,String query){
                    query=query.toLowerCase();
                    final List<TopSample>fliterdModelList=new ArrayList<>();
                    for(TopSample model:models){
                        final String text=model.getVocab().toLowerCase();
                        if (text.contains(query)){
                            fliterdModelList.add(model);
                        }
                    }
                    return fliterdModelList;
                }

            });



        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getTag().equals(TAG_BOOKMARKS)){
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Bookmarks.class));
        }
        if (v.getTag().equals(TAG_ABOUT_US)){

        }

    }
}
```

StudentAdapter file:

```
public class StudentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<StudentAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<TopSample> wordslist= Collections.emptyList();



    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView sword;
        public MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            sword=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vocab);
        }

    }



    public StudentAdapter(List<TopSample> wordslist){
        this.wordslist=wordslist;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dictionary_list_row,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder vh=new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;

        //return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TopSample sample=wordslist.get(position);
        holder.sword.setText(sample.getVocab());




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return wordslist.size();
    }

    //SearchinRecyclerview
    public void setFilter(List<TopSample> mTopSamples){
        wordslist=new ArrayList<>();
        wordslist.addAll(mTopSamples);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
//SearchinRecyclerview end

}
```

dictionary_list_row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"

                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/vocab"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />



</LinearLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your `dictionary_list_row.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/vocab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Country Name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Code"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**Update:**

Make some change here add `if` section

```
        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
        databaseAccess.open();
        Cursor cursor= databaseAccess.getInfo();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
            if(cursor.getString(0) != null){
               TopSample topSample=new TopSample(cursor.getString(0));
               wordlist.add(topSample);
              }
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        databaseAccess.close();
```